# How to use ModuleConfiguration and ModuleInitializer in swifty_viper implementation

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I have generated a new VIPER module in my application using Generamba (https://github.com/strongself/Generamba) with it's `swifty_viper` template. It has generated a module which have `Configurator` group with "ModuleConfigurator.swift" and "ModuleInitializer.swift" files.

The question is how should I use them?

Comment: reference to template - https://github.com/strongself/generamba-catalog/tree/master/swifty_viper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ModuleInitializer` is object that you can add to storyboard. Not needed if you init module from the source code.
`ModuleConfigurator` will setup main relations between VIPER components.

You do not need to add any code to `ModuleInitializer`, it is support class to setup module from storyboard.
But you may add some additional configuration to `ModuleConfigurator`. for example inject some shared network manager to interactor, or something like this.